# SQL Database Restore Error "3154"

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore a database backup, but I am getting this error:

> the backup set hold a backup of database other than the existing
>   database restore database is terminating abnormally )microsoft sql
>   server error 3154

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use WITH REPLACE while using the RESTORE command (OR)

Go with this link u may get answer

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/23/sql-server-fix-error-3154-the-backup-set-holds-a-backup-of-a-database-other-than-the-existing-database-ssms/

Answer (score 0):

This is my successful with the error when restore database.

Step1: Create a new database (ex. Production)

Step2: Stop SQL Server service

Step3: Delete 2 files generated from the new database (Production.mdf & PoductionLog.log)

Step4: Restart SQL Server service again

Step5: Restore the database from the backup file .bak

Hope this can help you!

Thai